# How do I remove "Permission denied" from this output? + bash

Tags: bash

How do I remove "Permission denied" from this output?

```
$ du -ksh * | sort -n -r | grep -v "Permission denied"
du: cannot read directory `$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-18': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory `$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-21-1952864042-553127817-1365347855-1002': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory `$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-21-1952864042-553127817-1365347855-500': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory `$Recycle.Bin/S-1-5-21-1995575548-1017590607-168656324-2178': Permission denied
```

I have tried the following:

`du -ksh * | sort -n -r | grep -v "Permission denied"`

`du -ksh * | sort -n -r 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can eliminate grep from the pipe if we eliminate errors from du:

```
du -ks * 2>/dev/null | sort -n -r
```

Removing grep speeds up by an order of magnitude. Also removing -h switch for du will help the numeric sort do the right thing and show the largest files on the top of the list.

Comment: tks this probably gets it as it removes the grep.

Answer (score 1):

The errors are coming from `du`, not `sort`, so you need to redirects its `stderr`. And you should probably filter them out before sorting; it doesn't make a difference to the result, but sorting is expensive so you should try to minimize its input.

```
du -ksh * 2>&1 | grep -v 'Permission denied' | sort -n -r
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right in that you will need to filter stderr, not stdout (or redirect one to the other before filtering). However, it seems like you are redirecting the output of sort, not of du.